# (django) razorpayx webhook receiving empty queryset instead of any payload

Tags: django, integration, razorpay, payout, razorpay-andoid-sdk

this is my webhook url i am using ngrok service for this

```
https://061c-103-223-8-94.in.ngrok.io/intg/rzpwhook/
```

[image]

when i try to change any payout status. i am getting empty queryset instead of any payload

this is my view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def RazorWebhook(request):
    print('webhook alert=============',request.POST)
    return render(request,'intg/rzpweebhook.html')
```

in terminal what i got :

```
webhook alert============= <QueryDict: {}>
```

[image]

is there anything that i am missing ?

Comment: I have same issue with another API, did you find the solution?